# How to run Blazor app projet in subfolder of Razor Dotnet core projet?

Tags: razor, blazor, subdirectory, razor-pages

I have one Asp Dot Net Core project, using Razor page, that is the ClientApp.

I create a new projet, using Blazor, that is the AdminApp.

I reference the AdminApp within the ClientApp.
I would like to call the AdminApp, from the ClientApp, when url is "clientapp/admin"

I cannot make it work.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would convert the ClientApp to blazor which should just require a couple lines being added to the startup.cs and then you can just import Admin components or update the route on top of the admin pages to include /admin/admincomponentname

This is the beauty of Blazor since serverside Blazor is essentially just razor pages with a small difference engine to run like a SPA.

Comment: Thks for your answer. I can answer, but the ClienApp already exist.
I just need to add the admin projet.
Any idea ?

Comment: You make no mention of what you are using for hosting or anything else. If you do not want to modify the Client application and 2 lines to the startup and want to run a blazor application in a subdirectory you need to have 2 separate "Web Apps" if using IIS then you can create a web application under the ClientApp, updating the MVC Routing to exclude /admin for the built in router and then when you link to /admin/admincomponentname it will spin up the blazor web application